# Will the Samsung galaxy s7, run Ubuntu mobile OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am planning on buying a Galaxy s7 and run ubuntu's mobile OS on it, is the phone able to run it stably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as this [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) clearly states, there is currently no image for the Galaxy S7.
Also the folks from ubports.com are not working on it so the answer is no, sorry.

Comment: :( I'm very sad, but thank you. Any other Android alternative supported by the s7?